# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields - Limit Repeater Group to first item

Tags: wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the Wordpress plugin advanced custom fields. I am using the following to call in a Repeater Group on a page:

```
<?php         
$rows = get_field('machine_downloads');
if($rows){ ?>

    <?php foreach($rows as $row){ ?>
        <?php if($row['machine_downloads_file']){ ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $row['machine_downloads_file']; ?>" class="btn grey">+ Download PDF</a>
        <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

I would like to use the same Repeater Group on another page, but limit it to only display the first item in the Repeater group. Any one able to help?

thanks
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just access the first `'machine_downloads_file'` directly? Get rid of the `foreach`:

```
<?php         
    $rows = get_field("machine_downloads");
    if($rows[0]['machine_downloads_file']){
        echo '<a href="' . $rows[0]["machine_downloads_file"] . '" class="btn grey">+ Download PDF</a>';
    } 
?>
```

Comment: A little more educational info: in the future, if you have a variable that holds an array of data, you can [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) it to see what it holds. For the heck of it, I recommend you temporarily add `var_dump($rows);` to your file, just to see how my answer actually works in the back-end of things.